# Error during web service call in Xamarin Forms

Tags: web-services, xamarin.forms, asmx, webservice-client

I've added connected service via Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider (see picture) proxy class has been successfuly created.
Then, when I try execute sample method from this web service (`client.TestLanguageAsync()` - which returns string) I get null reference exception - but I dont know what is null, because details of exception are very poor (look on picture). Below is code.

```
private async void BtnTest_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://f9512056.f95.ficosa.com/WMS/WMSWebService.asmx");
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport) {
            Name = "basicHttpBinding",
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
        };
        TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
        binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
        binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
        WMSWebServiceSoapClient client = new WMSWebServiceSoapClient(binding, endpoint);
        string text = await client.TestLanguageAsync(); //This causes exception
        label.Text = text;
    } catch (Exception E) {
        label.Text = E.ToString();
    }
}
```

Look also on screen

[Adding service reference and exception screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsIiv.png)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: This is stack trace from exception:

Comment: at WebServiceInMobileTest.MainPage+<BtnTest_Clicked>d__2.MoveNext () [0x000de] in E:\Test reports\WebServiceInMobileTest\WebServiceInMobileTest\WebServiceInMobileTest\MainPage.xaml.cs:55

Comment: The stack trace indicates exactly where it's null, have a look at it. It could also be an exception within the method call indicated.

Comment: I cannot step into, I dont know where and what "d__2.MoveNext ()" is. I also cannot step into call method